# Fedora package contains no files?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

This is related to a question over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103646). The fellow is trying to install a new allocator called `tcmalloc` which is part of [`gperftools`](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools). We both installed it on Fedora but can't neither of us can find the library.

```
$ find /lib -name '*tcmalloc*'
$ find /lib64 -name '*tcmalloc*'
$
```

Looking further it appears no files are installed:

```
$ dnf repoquery gperftools
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:58 ago on Thu 30 Aug 2018 04:59:15 PM EDT.
gperftools-0:2.6.3-2.fc28.x86_64
$ dnf repoquery -l gperftools
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:16 ago on Thu 30 Aug 2018 04:59:15 PM EDT.
Package gperftools-2.6.3-2.fc28.x86_64 contains no files
```

I'm trying to understand what is going on. I don't recall the situation in the past.

Is this a packaging bug? Or is the empty package signifying something else?

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 28 (Twenty Eight)
Release:        28
Codename:       TwentyEight

$ uname -a
Linux goldmont 4.17.12-200.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Aug 3 15:01:13 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: "This is a metapackage which pulls in all of the gperftools (and pprof) binaries, libraries, and development headers, so that you can use them."

Answer (score 2):

This kind of turned out to be an unusual exercise. The was no `gperftools-dev` or `gperftools-devel` package. There is a `gperftools-libs` package but it does not install into `/lib` or `/lib64`:

```
$ dnf repoquery -l gperftools-libs
Fedora 28 - x86_64 - Updates                    9.6 MB/s |  23 MB     00:02
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:13 ago on Fri 31 Aug 2018 12:40:20 AM EDT.
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/4a
/usr/lib/.build-id/4a/f4daa98151a84c8d1bc754e67a2858dd2007f7
/usr/lib/.build-id/56
/usr/lib/.build-id/56/fbe67cd746e213211226bc753dc3924e53d883
/usr/lib/.build-id/59
/usr/lib/.build-id/59/4af3ce60de4d29e773f783c434786d87e0431a
/usr/lib/.build-id/5d
/usr/lib/.build-id/5d/26545cd8d2417e42085614cecfb11bfcbbef58
/usr/lib/.build-id/66
/usr/lib/.build-id/66/bc072ca02ea7494c5f61d62c5d4f8abb83a37c
/usr/lib/.build-id/ef
/usr/lib/.build-id/ef/eedf93824216ffecac806dd60e3b4d23a7d8d1
/usr/lib64/libprofiler.so.0
/usr/lib64/libprofiler.so.0.4.16
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib/.build-id
/usr/lib/.build-id/70
/usr/lib/.build-id/70/532fbec5f8efae416a3d93452a41f40e866256
/usr/lib/.build-id/73
/usr/lib/.build-id/73/b36a618c8b93ffc6fb8bb6ac29932446b38c9f
/usr/lib/.build-id/73/ce1d567d60ea7a3fc84d6439e7e969465f6eb0
/usr/lib/.build-id/98
/usr/lib/.build-id/98/0ba2c89b28afdcec32e60fbba456fe9185e631
/usr/lib/.build-id/9e
/usr/lib/.build-id/9e/eb05e4484712cb7986c9e809d40d2869e3ab1f
/usr/lib/.build-id/b1
/usr/lib/.build-id/b1/be0e43fcc0d1fda1c56672f550046cc37ac9e8
/usr/lib/libprofiler.so.0
/usr/lib/libprofiler.so.0.4.16
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.5.1
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4
/usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4.5.1
```

I think that explains why `-ltcmalloc` fails to link on Fedora. Apparently the linker does not use `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: The linker does use `/usr/lib` etc., but it needs a `.so` (with nothing after `.so`) — there are none in the list of files above.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. Doesn't `%post` or `post_install` create symlinks in RPM? (It has been several years since I worked on a RPM package so I just don't recall).

Comment: Nothing should be installed into `/lib` or `/lib64` anymore, not for [many years now](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yeah, I'm not sure what is going on with things. I've never had so much trouble installing and using a package.

Comment: @jww typically the `.so`s and links are produced by the build, and referenced in the appropriate `%files` declaration; see [`gperftools`’ spec file](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/gperftools/blob/master/f/gperftools.spec).

Comment: @jww It may be somewhat late, but `ld` gives misleading results when trying to link statically, I only got some clue after `-L/papth/to/.so/folder -l:libprofiler.so` that stated the failure trying to link statically.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you didn’t find the `gperftools-devel` package, but that is the one you’re looking for. Really though I think the package maintainer intends users to install [`gperftools`](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/gperftools), since the description of that package says

> This is a metapackage which pulls in all of the `gperftools` (and `pprof`)
>   binaries, libraries, and development headers, so that you can use them.

`gperftools-devel` ships the development symlinks for `libtcmalloc`. The latest build for FC 28 [dates back to February 2018](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1029613) and was successful on all architectures. Installing `gperftools` pulls in `gperftools-devel`.